# Server 2008 R2 permissions not working

Tags: networking, permissions, domain, directory, sql-server-2008-r2

First of all: i posted this yesterday but put in the wrong email so I can't access it again.

I am configuring a 2008 R2 server for learning experience. The problem I'm having is the following:

Current situation: I created 5 Users, put the users in a global group and made the global group member of a domain local group. I then proceeded to make give the Domain Local Group permissions to enter my ''Administration'' folder. When the users in the group try to open the folder, it says ''you need permission to perform this action''

So in short, I gave the domain local group permissions full control to the ''administration'' folder and they cannot access it when I try to access it by entering the network location in Windows file explorer.

What I attempted: Restarting the clients, and servers. I recreated the users and recreated the groups aswell as the folder I am trying to give users access to. I also attempted giving permission to the folder by just using Global Groups(so without the Domain Local Group part) and that did work. But I need to learn how to do it via AGDLP(so with the domain local group)

Desired situation: The users in the global group which is in the domain local group specified above, can access the ''Administration'' folder and create files and folders in it. There is very little information I could find about this problem on the internet.

I hope to get help here.

Comment: "you need permission to perform this action'' - isn't that just UAC asking for permission?